# How to integrate WhatsApp with rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, whatsapp, whatsapi

How to integrate WhatsApp with rails application? or how to send a message using rails application.

Is there any gem or plugin available?

Comment: yes i search but i don't get any specific answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use twilio for sending whatsapp messages - 

https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp

They only problem is that they don't provide service for sending whatsapp messages in India as of today.

But you can send whatsapp messages in India using textlocal(third party service provider).
You can find documentation here -
https://api.textlocal.in/docs/send-whatsapp

You can use this gem as well - 
https://github.com/getninjas/whatsapp

To use this gem, you would require to follow the documentation provided by facebook. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

This gem could be useful for the Whatsapp Cloud API.

https://github.com/ignacio-chiazzo/whatsapp_sdk

This is an example:

```rb
client = WhatsappSdk::Api::Client.new(ACCESS_TOKEN) # replace this with a valid access_token
messages_api = WhatsappSdk::Api::Messages.new(client)
phone_numbers_api = WhatsappSdk::Api::PhoneNumbers.new(client)

phone_numbers_api.registered_number("107878721936019")
phone_numbers_api.registered_numbers("114503234599312") 

messages_api.send_text(sender_id: SENDER_ID, recipient_number: RECEIPIENT_NUMBER, message: "hola")
messages_api.send_location(
  sender_id: SENDER_ID, recipient_number: RECEIPIENT_NUMBER, 
  longitude: 45.4215, latitude: 75.6972, name: "nacho", address: "150 elgin street"
)
```

More examples [on this file](https://github.com/ignacio-chiazzo/ruby_whatsapp_sdk/blob/main/example.rb).

Answer (score -1):

I found a couple of them but I haven't tried them and the last commit was 3-4 years ago so not sure if they still work,

https://github.com/ongair/whatsapi

https://github.com/wawandco/whathor